# Mass percentage of limonene in a sample

Tags: organic-chemistry, mole

I realize Chemistry Stack Exchange is not for homework and this will seem incredibly simple to many of you, but I have received no help elsewhere. I would really appreciate any support:

> Limonene is obtained in the oil of lemon feel and it is the only alkene present.

> [image: Limonene]

> $\pu{0.500 g}$ of the oil reacted with exactly $\pu{30.6 cm3}$ of a solution of bromine dissolved in cyclohexane with a concentration of $\pu{0.200 mol dm-1}$.
> Calculate the percentage by mass of limonene in the oil.
> Give your answer to an appropriate number of significant figures.
> Assume that there is nothing else in the oil that react with bromine.

**What I have done:**
I tried working out the moles of $\ce{Br2}$ from these data (using the concentration and volume) and got $\pu{0.00612 mol}$. Assuming $\ce{Br2}$ is in the same ratio as limonene the moles will also be $\pu{0.00612 mol}$. However, this gives yield of $\pu{0.832 g}$ for limonene, which surely can’t be possible given the starting mass. Have I miscalculated the moles of bromine because it is dissolved in cyclohexane? Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: How many moles of bromine can be additioned to one mole of limonene?

Comment: You are almost there: you have a factor of two problem, i.e., there are two double bonds in limonene.

Comment: Thank you for the help, seems so simple now!

Comment: If you calculated correctly, there should be 83.4% limonene in your sample.

Comment: @Eliza: Please do not attach word problem as an image. Please type it in.